Path of Exile 2: are secondary weapon buffs active when not used?
Following up on the same question from the prequel: In Path of Exile, do secondary weapons help when equipped, but not used?
Does this work the same in the sequel?
An example: my primary weapon is a quarter staff that grants +10 dexterity while my equiped secondary weapon grants +10 life. Are both buffs always active when equiped, or do only the buffs work from the active weapon?

Please, use the correct tag game when available

No.
Only the active weapons stats are taken in account. You can easily check yourself by equipping any weapons with Strength, since Strength give Maximum Life, by switching active weapon you will see your maximum Life change value.
